# R shiny mapping output to input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building my first shiny app and I've run into a little difficulty which i cant understand

My code wants to take the input from the user - add one then print the output 
please ignore the radio buttons for now -

```
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("alpha"),

    sidebarPanel(numericInput("expn", 
                              "Please enter total number of reports received", 1,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 1000000
    ),
     radioButtons(inputId = "'QC_Type'", label = "QC Type", 
                 choices = c("Overall", "Solicited", "Spontaneous", 
                             "Clinical Trial","Literature" ),


    mainPanel(
      textOutput("results"))

    ))))





  server <- function (input, output) {
    output$results <- renderText(
    { print(1 +(Input$expn))
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm unable to see any output when I run the code.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of where your `mainPanel`is located. It should follow the `sidebarPanel`. Also, I recommend using `as.character()` instead of `print()`, unless you really want to print out the output on the console.

Here's the corrected code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("alpha"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput(
      "expn",
      "Please enter total number of reports received",
      1,
      min = 0,
      max = 1000000
    ),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "'QC_Type'",
      label = "QC Type",
      choices = c(
        "Overall",
        "Solicited",
        "Spontaneous",
        "Clinical Trial",
        "Literature"
      )
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("results"))
))

server <- function (input, output) {
  output$results <- renderText({
    as.character(1 + (input$expn))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I recommend using good practices when indenting code. It makes things easier to read and to find where braces and parentheses are.